# Joomla Administrator Plugins?

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

Is it possible to have Admin Plugins? Or are plugins only for the Site?

What I want is to have a notification system (not email) on the Admin side very much like Facebook. The trigger for such notifications is from the Site.

I've scanned through these [events](http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events) for Plugins and implemented a very simple content plugin (just testing `onContentAfterTitle`) for Site only.

**Questions**

1. Do these events also apply to the Admin side?
2. Is it possible to have an `Admin Plugin` that selects notifications from the database and displays them on screen?

Or if you guys can recommend an existing extension, that would be of great help. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The plugins are available for both side admin and site.

the difference is based on the events used inside the plugin.

for example `onContentAfterSave` event on the content plugin trigger when an article is saved.
its available in both side when an admin saves articles it trigger, also from site users post articles then also it will trigger.

Some events that are applied only on the site like 
`onContentPrepare,onContentAfterTitle, onContentBeforeDisplay,onContentAfterDisplay etc`

so which event is choose based on that the plugin works!.

The notification plugins you are looking for  is what does exactly ? then only we can suggest an event or plugin like its related to article,  user or something else.

Hope its make sense..